# Problem sending eth from contract to contract

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


contract Client  {
 
    address payable private hub;
    address payable public owner;
    uint256 public balance;

    
   
    constructor(address payable _hub) {
        hub = _hub;
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    
    receive() payable external {
        balance += msg.value;
    }    

  
    
    function withdraw(address payable destAddr) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can withdraw funds"); 
        uint amount = address(this).balance;
        destAddr.transfer(amount);
    }
    
    function start() public payable {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can start the process"); 
        uint amount = address(this).balance;
        hub.transfer(amount);
        balance = 0;
    }  

    function setHub(address payable  _new) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can change address");
        hub = _new;   
    }  
}
```

Hi i have a problem, when I deploy this contract and put as input (hub) the other contract, then send eth to this contract, i call the "start" function and throw a gas estimation error.
Someone who can help me pls...

I'm expecting that calling the start function fund will be sent to the other contract that also have a function for receiving eth

```
receive() payable external {
        balance += msg.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that gas estimation error because your `receive` function on the second contract is not empty and the transaction does not have enough gas to execute the code. `transfer` only sends the amount of gas necessary to execute a transfer of ether (21,000 gas) and nothing more.

You can use `call` instead of `transfer` to send ether and set the amount of gas that you want to send. `transfer` is actually no longer recommended for sending ether.

Comment: I was wrong here regarding the amount of gas on transfer. Transfer sends 2300 gas and throws an error when it fails (https://solidity-by-example.org/sending-ether/).